# Default get method that returns specific property - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, class, methods, get

I'm in the process of refactoring some MATLAB legacy software involving data obtained during a broad set of tests. I'm trying to create a class that contains the data of each individual channel, together with some extra info (e.g. its physical units).

Just for the sake of placing this question here, the class could look like this:

```
classdef Channel < handle
    properties (Access = 'private')
        prvValue, prvUnits;
    end

    properties (Dependent)
        value, units;
    end

    methods
        function this = Channel(value, units)
            this.value = value;
            this.units = units;
        end

        function set.value(this, value)
            this.prvValue = value;
        end

        function out = get.value(this)
            out = this.prvValue;
        end

        function set.units(this, units)
            this.prvUnits = units;
        end

        function out = get.units(this)
            out = this.prvUnits;
        end                  
    end
end
```

You can create an object of such a class with something like:

```
> ch1 = Channel([1:10], 'm');
```

And access to its dependent properties with:

```
>> ch1.value

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> ch1.units

ans =

    'm'
```

This would nonetheless require to change every single line in the legacy code that access to the data from something like "ch1" to "ch1.value".

Now my question: is there any way to define a sort of "default get method" that returns a particular property of the class ("value", in this case)? In other words, something that behaves like this:

> ```
> >> ch1
>
> ans =
>
>      1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
>
> >> ch1.units
>
> ans =
>
>     'm'
> ```

Any help will be welcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

No, `ch1` by itself is the object. You can have MATLAB output "ans = 1 2 3 ..." if you type `ch1` by itself (by overloading the `display` method), but this will not actually assign that value to ans. In particular, you cannot change the result of `foo = ch1`, `foo` will always be the object itself.

On the other hand, you can overload the `double` method, such that `foo = double(ch1)` yields the same as `foo = ch1.value`.

---

Do note that

> I'm in the process of refactoring some MATLAB legacy software [...]

sort of automatically leads to

> This would nonetheless require to change every single line in the legacy code [...]

Refactoring code involves a lot of rewriting. If you don't want to change so much code, make the refactoring less invasive. Don't change a plain array to a complex object.

Comment: Thank for you reply, Cris. Not having to change a lot of other stuff was just one reason for my question, but I could live with that. There are actually other reasons involving other people why I wanted to retain the same syntax for accessing to the data as to standard arrays.

I pretty much agree with all your comments. Unfortunately those alternatives don't accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Guillermo: You could collect all ways in which people use this array, and see if you can overload enough methods to make the behaviour similar. The one thing you cannot overload is the assignment `foo = ch1`, `foo` will be identical to `ch1`, not just a plain array. But you can overload `ch1(index)`, `max(ch1)`, and any other function that your users apply to `ch1` to ensure that the behaviour is consistent. And as I said, you can overload how the object is displayed to the output.

Comment: Overloading the display method is not a solution. It's not even used in the software, I just used it for describing my problem in the OP. Please give a look to my own reply and let me know if you see anything wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

I have in the meantime found something that seems -so far- to do exactly what I was aiming at: make the new class inherit from MATLAB's standard double class:

> ```
> classdef ChannelDouble < double
>     properties
>         units
>     end
>
>     methods
>         function this = ChannelDouble(data, units)            
>             this = this@double(data);
>             this.units = units;            
>         end
>     end  
> end
> ```

This class returns:

```
 >> ch1 = ChannelDouble([1:10], 'm')

ch1 = 

  1×10 ChannelDouble array with properties:

    units: 'm'

  double data:
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10

>> ch1.^2  % <--- Standard notation returns the data just like a double array would do

ans =

     1     4     9    16    25    36    49    64    81   100

>> ch1.units

ans =

    'm'
```

If anybody can think of a better solution, please let me know. Otherwise I will leave this reply here in case it can help anybody with a similar problem.

Comment: That is really interesting!

Comment: Do note the difference between handle classes and non-handle classes (i.e. normal classes). In the Q you had a handle class. The behavior is significantly different, and you need to remember to do things like `ch1 = ch1.setSomeValue(0)` with normal classes. IMO, handle classes should not be used for data, only for objects that encapsulate some resource (such as graphics objects, files, etc.), since they do not follow the standard MATLAB concept of pass by value.

Comment: `ch2 = ch1.^2` returns a double in `ch2`? That's unfortunate. I'm going to have to experiment with this idea. Thanks for posting!

Comment: I'm aware of that and will keep your comment in mind, although I don't see any issue with that at this point. I think I have never implemented a non-handle class in MATLAB. I learnt what a class was in C++ before I even tried it in MATLAB, so I guess handle classes are just the natural way to go for me.

That doesn't prevent the output of the get method to be returned per value, as usual in MATLAB, and as any other operation would expect it to be.